# Is a 2-D periodic structure isomorphic with the surface of a torus, a sphere, neither or both?

Tags: computational-chemistry, symmetry

When I was reading through the ADF-BAND tutorials, one of the toy systems presented was a 1-D periodic structure involving 3 collinear hydrogen atoms. The tutorial pointed out that, topologically speaking, this is cylindrically symmetrical (more specifically, it's ring symmetrical).

In the instance of a 2-D structure, can the calculation be considered a model for the surface of a torus (this seems logical), a sphere (I doubt this because if you fit a rectilinear grid to a sphere you end up with two poles and dissimilar meridians and parallels), or other?

Bonus questions: Has anyone used periodic calculations to model electronic structure/chemistry on the surface of a sphere or torus? Can you introduce a curvature term to account for these structures having a finite size?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing, at least according to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21882/gravitation-in-a-space-that-is-topologically-toroidal

Comment: @Manishearth - the same as which?

Comment: I was saying that a repeating 2D space is the same as a torus (topologically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a 2D-periodic space can be mapped to a torus, but [that's more a question for the math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66789/if-a-rectangular-grid-where-left-right-and-top-bottom-wrap-can-be-mapped-o)…

Regarding your bonus question, why would there be? What would you do with it? Molecular structures are intrinsically 3D, so I don't see what you would do in a 2D (periodic or not) space? Even when we talk about planar or pseudo-2D structures (buckyball, nanotube, etc.) they are 3D objects with 3D electronic densities and wavefunctions.

---

*Edit:* 3D structures that are periodic in two dimensions and finite in the other one can be studied by many computational chemistry codes. They are often referred to as *slab calculations* or *surface calculations*. The most common issue is that of Coulombic interaction (or Poisson equation solver), which typically requires special treatment in the 2D case.

Comment: By 2-D I mean structures which are periodic in 2 dimensions but finite in a third. A potential motivation is to model tubular structures that are too large to feasibly solve aperiodically.

Comment: @RichardTerrett OK, I edited my answer accordingly… but I don't understand what you mean by “curvature term”, then.

Comment: By this I mean an element of the calculation that corrects for the distortion(s) of the plane arising from being mapped to a torus with non-zero local curvature.

Comment: @RichardTerrett then there is no need too… while the “mathematical” view of a 2D periodic space is akin to a 3D torus, I don't believe any technique out there would really physical cast the 2D structure onto a 3D torus to perform any simulation.

Answer (score 3):

2D periodic systems can be mapped to toruses, but not spheres. This is easy to see because in a sphere, parallel lines always intersect. In the periodic system parallel lines never intersect.

Regarding your bonus question: I don't know of anyone who has tried to use a periodic model to study a sphere or torus. But people have kind of gone the other way around, and [replaced a 3D periodic model with the surface of a 4D sphere](http://jcp.aip.org/resource/1/jcpsa6/v94/i1/p597_s1?isAuthorized=no). This allows you to avoid complications associated with long-range Coulomb interactions.